# Crash when calling a function from a second Java file

Tags: java, android, crash

I am relatively new to the android game and I am having an issue with my app crashing whenever I call a function from a second java class.

this is my main JAVA file:

```
    package mashuda.tools.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalculatorActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        Drawinterface layout = new Drawinterface();


        setContentView(layout.drawit());


    }

}
```

and it is calling this code:

```
 package mashuda.tools.calculator;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Drawinterface extends Activity { 
    /** Called when the activity is first created. 
     * @return */


        TableLayout drawit(){

            TableLayout maintable = new TableLayout(this);

            maintable.setStretchAllColumns(true);
            maintable.setShrinkAllColumns(true);

            TableRow banner = new TableRow(this);
            banner.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

            TableRow rowOutput = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow rowSeven = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow rowFour = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow rowOne = new TableRow(this);
            TableRow rowZero = new TableRow(this);


            //answer box
            TextView answer = new TextView(this);
            answer.setText("ANSWER");

            answer.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 18);

            answer.setBackgroundColor(-1);

            answer.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
            answer.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

            TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams();
            params.span = 5;

            //loads answer bar
            rowOutput.addView(answer, params);
            //first column
            //creates 7 key
            Button sevenkey = new Button(this);
            sevenkey.setText("7");
            sevenkey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates 8 key
            Button eightkey = new Button(this);
            eightkey.setText("8");
            eightkey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates 9 key
            Button ninekey = new Button(this);
            ninekey.setText("9");
            ninekey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates division key
            Button dividekey = new Button(this);
            dividekey.setText("/");
            dividekey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // loads top row
            rowSeven.addView(sevenkey);
            rowSeven.addView(eightkey);
            rowSeven.addView(ninekey);
            rowSeven.addView(dividekey);

            //creates 4 key
            Button fourkey = new Button(this);
            fourkey.setText("4");
            fourkey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates 5 key
            Button fivekey = new Button(this);
            fivekey.setText("5");
            fivekey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates 6 key
            Button sixkey = new Button(this);
            sixkey.setText("6");
            sixkey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates multiplication key
            Button multiplykey = new Button(this);
            multiplykey.setText("X");
            multiplykey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // loads keys into second row
            rowFour.addView(fourkey);
            rowFour.addView(fivekey);
            rowFour.addView(sixkey);
            rowFour.addView(multiplykey);


            //creates 1 key
            Button onekey = new Button(this);
            onekey.setText("1");
            onekey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates 2 key
            Button twokey = new Button(this);
            twokey.setText("2");
            twokey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates 3 key
            Button threekey = new Button(this);
            threekey.setText("3");
            threekey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates add key
            Button addkey = new Button(this);
            addkey.setText("+");
            addkey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // loads keys into third row
            rowOne.addView(onekey);
            rowOne.addView(twokey);
            rowOne.addView(threekey);
            rowOne.addView(addkey);

            //creates 0 key
            Button zerokey = new Button(this);
            zerokey.setText("0");
            zerokey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates . key
            Button decimalkey = new Button(this);
            decimalkey.setText(".");
            decimalkey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates - key
            Button negativekey = new Button(this);
            negativekey.setText("+/-");
            negativekey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // creates equals key
            Button equalskey = new Button(this);
            equalskey.setText("=");
            equalskey.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

            // loads keys into fourth row
            rowZero.addView(zerokey);
            rowZero.addView(decimalkey);
            rowZero.addView(negativekey);
            rowZero.addView(equalskey);

            // loads rows into table
            maintable.addView(rowOutput); 
            maintable.addView(rowSeven); 
            maintable.addView(rowFour);
            maintable.addView(rowOne);
            maintable.addView(rowZero); 

            //sets view as maintable
            return (maintable);

}
}
```

I did add the second file to the android manifest.
and my compiler(eclipse) does not detect any errors.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Yes there is: it throws a runtime exception and that the main activity is unable to start

Comment: Can you include the crash output?

Comment: 02-17 21:13:59.791: E/AndroidRuntime(413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{mashuda.tools.calculator/mashuda.tools.calculator.CalculatorActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Does it refer to a line number? If so, which line of code is it?

Comment: It does not give a line number. The program compiles fine, but when it runs, it crashes and my debugger cannot tell me the line number

Comment: You don't get a line number on that NullPointerException?

Comment: it is telling me line 1622, which does not make sense because i do not have 1000+ lines of code

Comment: Why don't you post the entire stacktrace? Or at least the first dozen lines.

Comment: ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1622 
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1638 
ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 117 
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 928 
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 3647

Comment: Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method] 
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 507 
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 839 
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 597 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating your TableLayout programatically use an xml resource file.

Here is a tutorial on this: http://huuah.com/using-tablelayout-on-android/

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code, here is the error I got, no answer yet, but this may help others

```
02-17 20:00:27.020: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1176): GC freed 30619 objects / 777176 bytes in 06ms
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1777)
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:279)
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.<init>(LinearLayout.java:88)
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.widget.TableLayout.<init>(TableLayout.java:90)
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.android.demo.notepad1.Drawinterface.drawit(Drawinterface.java:20)
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at com.android.demo.notepad1.CalculatorActivity.onCreate(CalculatorActivity.java:25)
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-17 20:32:10.830: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1222):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all no need to extends Activity for Drawinterface. While you create any View using java code. You need to extend View class or any child class of it. Here you may extend TableLayout.

Or simplest thing is create layout in xml. Java code creates unnecessary complexity while developing and even in understanding (As it is already created in above code).